# replace this file (located at /var/www/html/index.html) in Apache2 installed through LAMP in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, apache2, lamp

how  to replace this file (located at /var/www/html/index.html) in Apache2 installed through LAMP in ubuntu 18.04
whenever I tried to open any .html  or .php file it shows this error 
"Not Found

The requested URL ..... was not found on this server.

---

Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80"

and at localhost port 80 "Apache Ubuntu default page
It works! " opened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not by opening a website addres in your browser but by logging into the server and doing

```
cd /var/www/html
vi index.html
```

Or if it is a desktop you can also do

```
gedit index.html
```

(apply sudo if needed)